# Python Twisted - Return to the callback chain after errback

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, twisted, deferred

So, I have a callback chain, something like this:

```
deferred = create_deferred()
deferred.addCallback(cb1)
deferred.addCallback(cb2)
deferred.addCallback(cb3)
deferred.addCallback(cb4)

deferred.addErrback(start)
deferred.addErrback(eb1)

deferred.addBoth(end)
```

Inputs start in start() - which is also an Errback. In start, a deferred is created. It has 4 processing steps, cb1 through cb4. If everything goes alright, the input should go through the 4 processing steps and finally in end() - from addBoth.

If something goes wrong along the way (in cb1 or cb2, etc), they should go to start() where the input will be "retried" several times. If there are no more retries or if something wrong happens in start() it should go to eb1 and than end().

My problem is, even if there are retries for a certain input, it still goes to eb1 and than in end.

How can I make my deferred return to the callback chain if it encounters an error?

[image]

Now, if, for example, I have an error in CB2, the deferred goes to START, but even if it still has retries, it still goes to EB1. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem, but a http://sscce.org would be super useful to really understand the specifics of your problem to ensure that a proposed solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if EB1 is called after START, then START must be returning some sort of Failure value. That's how Twisted knows whether to go down the callback chain or the errback chain.